# Android Studio palette attributes problem

Tags: android-studio

Why don't all of the attributes appear ?

[image: button attributes screenshot]

For example, there are many important properties that do not appear like :

`onClick` , `hint` , `text` , .....etc.

Comment: Why not just edit the XML?

Comment: Only appear attributes that you have in the xml. if you want to see a complete list, see the reference https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the "Common Attributes" section, like so:

[image]

**EDIT:**

If you don't see it, just edit it in the XML, for example

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:conClick="something"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see all the field that you need in your palette side on android studio,
simply switch to the xml code of your views and manually add it into your xml's tag.
for example if you missed the Hint in an editable EditText palette just add the following xml line (android:hint="") without space into your xml code and the hint will appear in your design palette:
It works perfectly for me. Hope it helps.